# How to delete the first matched pattern in unix

Tags: shell

I want to delete the character from first line to till first matched pattern.
Ex : 
xyz@abc:Hello:1234 xyz

I want to replace first character to till first matched pattern : (I don't want to delete all)

I need result like :

Hello:1234 xyz

Please can anyone help me on this .

Comment: Is this data in a file or in a variable?

Comment: All the contents are in a file

Comment: And you want to delete all the lines and characters before the first colon?

Comment: yes i need it in same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '!p && p=index($0, ":"){$0=substr($0, p+1)} p' file
```